# Change Launcer Icon of the Application

Tags: java, android

Can anybody tell me that how to change the default launcher icon for the specific activity and will again change for others activity as it was before. Thanks

Comment: Ok then do it and tell me after done. plz i want to know...

Comment: Activity has no launcher icon. Application has a launcher icon and it can't be  change programmatically.

Comment: @FarhanAli When you say "everything is possible in programming", doesn't that include that something is *not* possible?

Comment: Icon is also compiled with all sources and manifest file. Anything which is compiled and wrapped cannot be changed in any programming. App icon is registered in `R.java` which is not changeable

Comment: like for you @Ascorbin :-)

Comment: yeah... sorry o all of you guys.

Comment: sorry to say @MD but i have joined stackoverflow from a year. but i have logged in from my new google account. which i have created priviously

Comment: @FarhanAli We are always here to helping every one. always ready to give suggestion to new bies.

Comment: okay @MD. i will remember it next time. i was wrong. i have accepted my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Activities don't have icons your app does.You can change icon of your app from manifest file. First you have to add an icon into **drawable** folder under **res** and then from manifest give the name of your icon: `android:icon="@drawable/new_icon"` And as said on the comments you can't change it after compilation.